# Send a video with socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, websocket, socket.io

I can't seem to find a solution to send videos with socket.io.
I would like to select a video from a react-native app and send them with socket.io to save them to a folder.

I tried to send them in **base64** using **expo-image-picker** and **expo-image-manipulator** with react-native, I get them fine in the folder, but unable to play the video.

I am calling you to see if there is another solution to this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: The most efficient way to upload a large file to the server is through BLOB format then convert to your favorite output format ( MP4, 3GP, or any other).  Does server support BLOB file?

Comment: In my research I saw this BLOB format pass, but also Uint8Array, Buffer!
I am on my own dedicated server

Comment: But from react-native, do I have to send a file in base64 format or convert it to blob format? 

Comment: If your server support BLOB, fetch video in BLOB format then upload BLOB